# How to send e-mail from Django to more than 10 thousand subscribers without getting out of memory

Tags: django, newsletter, django-mailer

I am using the basic version of Webfaction server to host my web application written in Python/Django. I am adding newsletter feature. There are more than 10 thosuand subscribers are still growing. How to send the newsletter to each of them. This is what I am doing right now. It can send about 200 emails and get out of memory.

```
for subscriber in subscribers:
    send_email(title, content, 'sender', subscriber)
```

What's the best way to handle this in a shared hosting server with limited resources.

Thank you

Comment: Use a queue based approach,and a daily job to trigger the sending of emails. https://github.com/dstegelman/django-mail-queue

Comment: I tried using `django-mail-queue` but couldn't configure celery on webfaction easily hence no async calls thus process failed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a service for sending out the emails, many benefits that you don't have to build out yourself. That way you can fire off thousands of emails and your Django web server won't have to slow down and handle each email. You'll also get the ability to track bounces and have much more reliable sending.

[SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) - With [django-sendgrid](https://github.com/RyanBalfanz/django-sendgrid)

There are a few other services out there like [Postmarkapp](https://postmarkapp.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. `SendGrid` looks very fair but there is nothing mentioned about queue based approach. Regarding `Postmarkapp`, I am not looking for the paid solutions.

Comment: In order to queue emails you'd have to use a task system for Django like Celery (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) and then use Django-Post-Office (https://github.com/ui/django-post_office) to queue up emails and manage them with templates.

Comment: Mailgun (http://www.mailgun.com/) is another service provider. You can use their service to send up to 10000 mails/month for free. If you send more mails than that a fee is added per mail.